# MS ACCESS: Unable to retrieve LAST Price Paid based on Maximum Date

Tags: sql, ms-access

**OBJECTIVE**

Develop a sales catalog for a `COMPANY ID` based on `ITEM ID` and latest `PRICE` paid (based on `LAST SHIP DATE`).

**APPROACH**

1. Pull in `CUSTOMER`, `SALES`, `ITEM` Tables
2. Run Query Link tables based off of `CUSTOMER ID` and `ITEM` to understand purchase history
3. Export a table showing a `COMPANY ID`, `ITEM ID`, `LAST SALES PRICE`, `LAST SHIP DATE`

**CODE**

```
SELECT 
[Sales Order Details (F42119)].SDAN8 AS [COMPANY ID], 
[Sales Order Details (F42119)].SDITM AS [ITEM ID], 
[Sales Order Details (F42119)].SDAITM AS STYLE, 
(CCur([SDLPRC])/10000) AS PRICE, 
Max([Sales Order Details (F42119)].SDDRQJ) AS [LAST SHIP DATE] 

INTO [Table - Sales Details]
FROM [Sales Order Details (F42119)]

GROUP BY 
[Sales Order Details (F42119)].SDAN8, 
[Sales Order Details (F42119)].SDITM, 
[Sales Order Details (F42119)].SDAITM, 
(CCur([SDLPRC])/10000);
```

**ISSUE/QUESTION**

1. `CUSTOMER` **A** bought `ITEM` **ABC** @ 3 different prices on 3 different dates. I've taken the `Max` of `Ship Date` in hope to show the **LAST** `PRICE` **PAID** (resulting in one single value for price). However, for some reason, I am still receiving the *three different prices on three different dates*. **How can I have MS Access only display the latest price based off of the latest ship date?**

*NOTE: SDLPRC = "Sold Price". I have to convert SLDPRC into a Currency and then divide by 1000; this is due to our current database setup. Also, `SDAITM` is an "Abbreviated Item Number" that is more customer-friendly.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're grouping by your Price variable `(CCur([SDLPRC])/10000)`.  When you use `GROUP BY`, Access/SQL will split the rows by *all* the variables in the `GROUP BY` statement.  So you need to not group by price.

Change your query to use a subquery that finds the last date of a sale grouped by `[Company ID]`, `[Item ID]` and `Style`.  The use an outer query to grab the price for that particular record.  Something like:

```
SELECT b.[COMPANY ID], b.[ITEM ID], b.STYLE, b.[LAST SHIP DATE], CCur(a.[SDLPRC])/10000 as PRICE
INTO [Table - Sales Details]
FROM [Sales Order Details (F42119)] as a
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        [Sales Order Details (F42119)].SDAN8 AS [COMPANY ID], 
        [Sales Order Details (F42119)].SDITM AS [ITEM ID], 
        [Sales Order Details (F42119)].SDAITM AS STYLE, 
        Max([Sales Order Details (F42119)].SDDRQJ) AS [LAST SHIP DATE] 
    FROM [Sales Order Details (F42119)]
    GROUP BY 
        [Sales Order Details (F42119)].SDAN8,
        [Sales Order Details (F42119)].SDITM, 
        [Sales Order Details (F42119)].SDAITM 
    ) as b
ON a.SDAN8 = b.[COMPANY ID]
   and a.SDITM = b.[ITEM ID]
   and a.SDAITM = b.STYLE
   and a.SDDRQJ = b.[LAST SHIP DATE]
```

Comment: Thank you - this confirms my suspicion